# What is the reason to use AMQP instead of Beanstalkd?

Tags: data-structures, queue, scalability, amqp, beanstalkd

Why use one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

amqp is a standard, beanstald is a queue.
Read http://www.amqp.org/confluence/display/AMQP/AMQP+Specification for more details.
You can also visit rabbitMQ website for some introductory information